# My location coordinates in android

Tags: android, gps, location, maps

im trying to get my current location got from gps coordinates.. i saw lots of examples of how should i do that. When i try to merge my code with sample code, i get an eror on this line :

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1, 0, locationListener);
```

and it says :

```
The method requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, LocationListener) in the type LocationManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, LocationListener)
```

Where could be a problem..? Spend hours looking for problem..

```
public class MyLocationDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, 
        LocationListener,
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener{
    GMapV2Direction md;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GeoPoint gp;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    LocationManager lm;
    private TextView mMessageView;
    Bundle extras;
    Location mycurrent;
    LatLng endpoint;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    static double currentlatid;
    static double currentlonid;

    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(16000) // 16 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16) // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        RouteActivity route = new RouteActivity();


        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location mostRecentLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(mostRecentLocation != null) {
            currentlatid=mostRecentLocation.getLatitude();
            currentlonid=mostRecentLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1, 0, locationListener);

        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        LatLng a = null;
        try {
            a = (LatLng) extras.get("coord");
        } catch (Exception x) {
        }
        if (a == null) {
            try {

                LatLng x = new LatLng(mycurrent.getLatitude(),
                        mycurrent.getLongitude());
                a = x;
                System.out.print(a);
            } catch (Exception x) {

            }

            System.out.print(a);
        }
        LatLng b ;
        try{
        b = (LatLng) extras.get("Obj1");
        endpoint = b;
        draw_route(a, b);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        LatLng c = null;
        try {
            c = (LatLng) extras.get("Obj2");
            endpoint = c;
            b = (LatLng) extras.get("Obj1");
            draw_route(b, c);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("smth went wrong");
        }
        try {
            LatLng d = (LatLng) extras.get("Obj3");
            endpoint = d;
            draw_route(c, d);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("smth went wrong");
        }

        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(a));

        try{
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        }catch(Exception e ){

        }


    }

    // }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,int status,Bundle extras){}
    };
    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
       // TextView myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        String latLongString = "";
        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
        } else {
            latLongString = "No location found";
        }
       // myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" + latLongString);
    }
    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getApplicationContext(), this, // ConnectionCallbacks
                    this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
        }
    }

    public void draw_route(LatLng start, LatLng finish) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        md = new GMapV2Direction();
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(54.72, 25.3);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 10));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start).title("Start"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(finish).title("End"));

        Document doc = md.getDocument(start, finish,
                GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
        int duration = md.getDurationValue(doc);
        String distance = md.getDistanceText(doc);
        String start_address = md.getStartAddress(doc);
        String copy_right = md.getCopyRights(doc);

        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(
                Color.RED);

        for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
        }

        mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
    }

    /**
     * Button to get current Location. This demonstrates how to get the current
     * Location as required without needing to register a LocationListener.
     */
    public void showMyLocation(View view) {

        if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            String msg = "Location = " + mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            mycurrent = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();


        }
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@link LocationListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMessageView.setText("Location = " + location);
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", 50000000)
        .show();
        draw_route(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), endpoint);
    }

    /**
     * Callback called when connected to GCore. Implementation of
     * {@link ConnectionCallbacks}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(REQUEST, this); // LocationListener
        mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
         System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n"+mCurrentLocation+"\n@@2222222@@@@@@@@@@@``");
    }

    /**
     * Callback called when disconnected from GCore. Implementation of
     * {@link ConnectionCallbacks}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@link OnConnectionFailedListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default
        // behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }
    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
          if (loc != null) {
              currentlatid = loc.getLatitude();
            currentlonid = loc.getLongitude();

            float accuracyd = loc.getAccuracy();
            String providershown = loc.getProvider();    



           }
        }
}}
```

Comment: see my answer !!!  check your import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two LocationListener class available in android

```
1. android.location.LocationListener
2. com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

make sure you are passing first one. Just check your import statement it must be `android.location.LocationListener`

Comment: @danny117 opponent already accepted my answer and it already solved his problem, you can see clearly the problem was that as i given in my answer then how you can say next answer is right.explain me what you are thinking about this problem. i think you are also giving wrong direction to other viewers of this answer.

Comment: @danny117 Do you really think this answer is wrong? This answer is working and right for the specific problem of "user3416113".

Comment: Fix the gramar in your answer and I'll up vote you.  I don't think its wrong I think following answer is better.  I mean all the user needed to do was pass a constant as a float by adding an f after the constant to tell the compiler that the constant was a float to fix his error.

Comment: @danny117 you can edit my answer if you are showing any grammer mistake. you can not vote down question because of only grammer mistake its against a policy of this site and yes i have given right answer based on opponent question and next answer is not a solution of opponent question you can clearly see.I think you should read again opponent question so you know what opponent asking. if you think my answer is wrong you can what down but i remind you opponent already accepted my answer thank you.

Comment: I gave are an upvote.  Still like answer below.  Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the documentation for the  LocationManager class the method  requestLocationUpdates 
requires the following parameters

```
    requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

In your case the type of minTime that you are passing to the method is of type int. Additionally the type of minDistance is also int.

You need to change minTime to a long and minDistance to a float. You can do this with the following code:

```
     long minTime = (long)1; 
     float minDistance = (float)0;
```

You can then call requestLocationUpdates as follows:

```
     lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1, 0, locationListener);
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: long minTime=1; float minDistance=0;  not need to cast check it in your editor